# If an NP problem reduces to an NPC problem, it is NPC?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete, reductions, np

Is the following statement true?

> If a problem P<sub>1</sub> is in NP and polynomial time reducible to P<sub>2</sub>, where P<sub>2</sub> is NP-complete, then P<sub>1</sub> is also NP-complete.

Intuitively I think the answer is 
No because I need to prove that it is NP-hard as well for P<sub>1</sub> to be NP-complete.
But I cannot get the exact proof.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "I need to prove that all NP Hard as well for p1 to be NPC". Informally, saying that a problem is NP-hard is saying "If I could solve this problem, I could solve everything in NP with only a little more work." Does the scenario of this question allow you to do that? Note also that the two possible answers to the question are "Yes, P1 is NP-complete: here's a proof" and "No, his doesn't prove that P1 is NP-complete: here's an explanation of why not." In the negative case, you can't prove that P1 *isn't* NP-complete because every NPC problem is also reducible to P2.

Comment: that was a typo I meant ''it is NP hard  as well for p1 to be NPC''(refering to the two properties for a problem to be NPC) @DavidRicherby.

Comment: OK -- now I understand what you're asking. So, you (correctly) think we're in the "no" case of my comment. You just need to explain why the P1 being polytime reducible to an NP-complete problem isn't a proof that P1 is NP-complete.

Comment: Yes..I can't put my finger on that :(..could you please elaborate

Comment: Hint: give a counter-example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: *Every* problem in NP is reducible to $P_2$. In particular, if $P_1$ is in NP but not NP-complete then it reduces to $P_2$ without being NP-complete. So the question is:

> Are there problems in NP which are not NP-complete?

Perhaps you can answer this question somehow. Try to think of the simplest possible problems.

Comment: I suggest rephrasing the question as follows:

"Are there problems in NP (but not in P) that are not NP-hard?"

Comment: Well, problems in P can't be NP-hard. Unless P = NP, of course...

Comment: I am not contesting the exercise, on the contrary. Just suggesting what I think would be a better version of the question, that's all. As it reads now, the answer would be trivially "yes", unless you assume implicitly what I have added.

Comment: Not to be byzantine, but assuming explicitly that the problem is not in P is, in my opinion, an informative hint that would enhance the educational value of the exercise.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23091/discussion-between-andre-souza-lemos-and-yuval-filmus).